How can I improve the feedback portion of my boost converter circuit?
I designed this boost converter to drive vacuum florescent displays, nixie tubes, and similar devices.
It can drive a 10k Ohm load at 235V. I'm sure I can get away with larger loads as alot of the tubes/displays only need a few mA.
I'm curious as to how others would have designed the feedback portion of this circuit, as I'm certain there is a more elegant way to implement something like this.
How do I improve the feedback for the boost converter? Currently it's just the output of a comparator that turns on/off a mosfet connected to a square wave oscillator. It does the job, but I get some ringing on the "test" node when M2 turns off.


@MXVG Why do you think it has much to do with feedback? The biggest problems with this circuit are not where you’re looking. Let’s start with the multivibrator. It wastes lots of power. Then the gate drive circuit for the power mosfet is basically missing. Feedback sense is probably the best done part of the whole circuit :)

There is an ideal diode for D1, you may want to put in a model for that.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Ah I see, thank you for your input! I'll try and come up with a more efficient oscillator. As for the gate drive circuit, do you think I could get away without one--if I was able to in the simulations?

You're using the kind of a simulator that doesn't burn your fingers. Look at power dissipations. The reason you think you can get away without a gate driver is because R1 and R8 dissipate 0.9W of power in total. At that point, the switching converter is wasting less power than the multivibrator. It's a problem that a simple push-pull emitter follower would fix. The multivibrator will run perfectly fine with say 100uA of collector current in Q1 and Q2. You could use a 555, since a 555 can be easily stopped and restarted, and it has a gate driver built-in :)

You may think that "I don't care about efficiency", but in this case low efficiency means potentially a lot of heat that you'll need to deal with. As shown, the efficiency of the circuit is <5% (!), i.e. it is a heater that just coincidentally makes some high voltage. Not great. To maintain efficiency, use a CMOS 555 (eg LMC555), and a CMOS comparator with push-pull output. At that point you may as well use any boost converter switcher chip with a cascode mosfet to allow a low-voltage converter to switch high voltage.

Building discrete circuits can be a fun challenge.  First off, just to make clear, they aren't in any way practical: this is an extremely solved problem, ICs are readily available, and even some very old parts remain effective, while newer parts gain more advanced features and continue to reduce in cost.  An application would have to be extremely specialized indeed (maybe, oh I don't know, MIL/aerospace application where a very limited sheet of approved, rad-hard, etc. devices are available?) to require such a solution -- or highly constrained in other respects (e.g. impoverished or trade-restricted countries where only common parts and salvage are available).
To wit: a UC3843 (old) or LM3481 (newer) would be an excellent choice for this sort of converter.
So let's have some fun.
First things first, we need to make sure our switching converter core (L1, M1, D1, C5) is working well.
A high ratio, in a single stage, does not perform well -- no matter how we control it.
To obtain e.g. 20mA at 240V, from 13V input, we need at least a peak current of \$2 (0.02\,\text{A})\frac{(240\,\text{V}) - (13\,\text{V})}{(13\,\text{V})}\$ = 0.7A, in BCM (at 1mH inductance, this runs at about 17kHz).  That's a lot of peak current, it's delivered in brief gulps to C5, the inductor has to be huge in value and yet low in DCR, the transistor has to handle full peak input current and output voltage, and the diode incurs much higher reverse recovery losses.
Granted, this is only 4.8W output, and even with the high duty cycle, fairly modest modern components are more than capable of handling this -- but there are many lessons we can learn by improving the design.  An optimal converter might fit into the same volume as the inductor or capacitor alone, here!
For such ratios, it's better to use a tapped or isolated flyback topology.  The PWM can be closer to 50%, peak currents and voltages are very modest (2-4x the DC value say), device ratings are mild, efficiency can be high, size can be small.
This might require winding a transformer, but there is another route: any old 5-18V, 5-20W flyback power supply will use a transformer of comparable ratings.  Just wire it in reverse, transformers don't know the difference!
Then for control, we could use a gated oscillator motif like that, but it's rather crude.  What if we want a quieter, more stable output?  (Quiet in both electrical and acoustic terms: the on-off pulsing will be audible!)  Or, what if the output gets overloaded, can we avoid pulling fault current through the transistor -- should we add some kind of current limiting to the circuit?
A good solution to both these issues is current-mode control.  We can demonstrate this with ye olde 555, but the aforementioned UC3843 or LM3481 are better suited to it, and the block diagrams and application notes on them are recommended resources.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Excerpted from: https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/555%20Boost.pdf (links to my website)
Ah, hmm.. well that was a lot of drawing effort just to use a blank 555 symbol.  Nevermind, I won't be simulating that here then.  Plain text will have to do today, I guess.
Anyway, VCTRL acts as a throttle (control voltage), setting the peak TRG voltage, which then discharges through R3 until it crosses VCTRL/2 (the internal threshold), turning on the output.  Output current rises (into the transformer) until the current-sense shunt resistor passes threshold; the threshold is determined by VCTRL and the bias point of Q2, a common-base amplifier, which has a non-inverting gain of about 10.  When M1 is off, Q2 normally pulls THR low, but as the shunt voltage rises, THR eventually rises above VCTRL, terminating the pulse.  This overall gives mostly-stable switching frequency, PWM controlled by peak inductor current (we're doing it definitionally by measuring inductor current and stopping the pulse at a dependent threshold; we can just also express this as a PWM function -- to quote Richard Feynman, [the PWM] "has some practical results, but that's not why we do it!"), and a control voltage we can vary with an error amplifier to furnish a stable output voltage.
Why control inductor current?  Because it's the process variable.  Regardless of what's happening at the input or output, the inductor current should never exceed nominal design limits.  Constrain that variable, and the converter can never blow up due to overcurrent, and as a bonus we limit peak input and output currents (at least, within modest ratio) so we get current limiting for free.  (The switch can still blow up due to overvoltage or overheating, but we can solve those separately, and hey, solving one entire failure mechanism is pretty big.)
Whereas with a voltage-mode PWM control (output voltage --> error amp --> PWM comparator), inductor current is a free variable and could build to arbitrarily high values, leaving the switch vulnerable.
